# Duplicate request sent by `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient`

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive, spring-webclient

This is the piece of code that sends the requests twice every time you call it

```
 suspend fun requestSimulation(simulationRequest: SimulationRequest): Boolean {
        val accepted = WebClient.create(simulationServiceHost)
            .post()
            .uri(simulationEndpoint)
            .bodyValue(simulationRequest)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(Boolean::class.java)

        accepted.subscribe { bool: Boolean -> logger.info(bool.toString()) }
        return accepted.awaitSingle()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the modified code that fixed the issue

```
suspend fun requestSimulation(simulationRequest: SimulationRequest): Boolean {
        return WebClient.create(simulationServiceHost)
            .post()
            .uri(simulationEndpoint)
            .bodyValue(simulationRequest)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Boolean::class.java)
            .awaitSingle()
    }
```